# Android autocompletetextview do not refresh after ArrayList changed in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I have searched around SO here and got suggested solution but doesn't work at all. Below are the code. First when the Fragment loaded, it query backend to get a list of String and it did populated to `AutoCompleteTextView`. Once user selected a string from `AutoCompleteTextView`, I will remove this string from `bagIdList` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but doesn't work at all.
What I discovered is that once `AutoCompleteTextView` has been `initialized` with some data (by `ArrayAdapter`), even afterward you changed the `ArrayList` which is with `ArrayAdapter`, `AutoCompleteTextView` will not change at all.

Appreciate anyone please assist in this issue. Thanks !

```
public class MaterialFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> bagIdList = new ArrayList<String>();    
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteBagId;    
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;    
    private Button save;    
    private View mView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("onCreateView = ", "MaterialInputFragment");    
        if(mView == null) {

            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_material_input, container, false);

        }    
        return mView;    
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    
        this.autoCompleteBagId = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.mView.findViewById(R.id.bagIdList);    
        this.save = (Button) this.mView.findViewById(R.id.saveInput);    
        retrieveBagId();    
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity(), R.layout.dropdown_list_item, bagIdList);    
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);    
        autoCompleteBagId.setAdapter(adapter);    
        autoCompleteBagId.setThreshold(1);            
        this.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                bagIdList.remove(selectedBagId);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });   

    }        

    private void retrieveBagId(){

        AsyncAppData<ProdProcess> aggregate = AppController.getInstance().getKinveyClient().appData("prodprocess", ProdProcess.class);    
        Query myQuery = AppController.getInstance().getKinveyClient().query();    
        GenericJson ex = new GenericJson();    
        ex.put("$exists", false);    
        myQuery.equals("companyid", AppController.getInstance().getUserData().getCompanyId()).and(new Query().equals("input_by", ex)).addSort("_kmd.ect", SortOrder.ASC);

        aggregate.get(myQuery, new KinveyListCallback<ProdProcess>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ProdProcess[] results) {

                bagIdList.clear();    
                Log.e(TAG, "results1 = " + results.length);    
                if(results.length > 0) {

                    for (ProdProcess prodProcess : results) {

                        bagIdList.add(prodProcess.getBagId());

                    }

                } 

               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {

                Log.e("", "Failed to retrieve bad ids : ", error);    
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.msg_failed_get_bagid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }    
        });    
    }    
}
```